# Setting Ringtone in Android

Tags: android, ringtone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set ringtone in Android from my activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271777/how-to-set-ringtone-in-android-from-my-activity)

I have sounds files in my res/raw folder and i want to select a sound to set as a ringtone on the click of a button. Wonder how can i do that?

Comment: have you ever found a solution?

Comment: This is not a duplicate! this talks about setting a ringtone from a raw file. The other one is just how to set a ringtone　already on the sd card. Please reopen i have a full solution.

Answer (score 28):

@Maxood

The code from @Clive is what you need to set the ringtone. You will need the absolute path to the file, which you can't get from a raw resource.

The solution is to get the resource file asset and write it to the sdcard 1st, before you give it to the content resolver for insertion.

```
File newSoundFile = new File("/sdcard/media/ringtone", "myringtone.oog");
Uri mUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.your.package/R.raw.your_resource_id");
ContentResolver mCr = app.getContentResolver();
AssetFileDescriptor soundFile;
try {
       soundFile= mCr.openAssetFileDescriptor(mUri, "r");
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       soundFile=null;   
   }

   try {
      byte[] readData = new byte[1024];
      FileInputStream fis = soundFile.createInputStream();
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newSoundFile);
      int i = fis.read(readData);

      while (i != -1) {
        fos.write(readData, 0, i);
        i = fis.read(readData);
      }

      fos.close();
   } catch (IOException io) {
   }
```

Then you can use the previously posted solution

```
       ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
   values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, newSoundFile.getAbsolutePath());
   values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "my ringtone");
   values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/oog");
   values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, newSoundFile.length());
   values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, R.string.app_name);
   values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
   values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
   values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
   values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

   Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(newSoundFile.getAbsolutePath());
   Uri newUri = mCr.insert(uri, values);


   try {
       RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getContext(), RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);
   } catch (Throwable t) {
       Log.d(TAG, "catch exception");
   }
```

Don't forget to write the the permission

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

in your manifest

hope this helps

Comment: Not trying to beat a dead horse here, but make sure you have the permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> in your manifest if you're writing to the SD card or else you will get an error.

Comment: Also to note:  Be sure to set the uri like so - Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.myapp/" + R.raw.my_resource); or Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.myapp/raw/my_resource");  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#openAssetFileDescriptor%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: You must create a raw directory in your project under res directory obvious maybe but not for me , my_resource is the file name minus the .extension

Comment: +1 works like a charm, please edit and add comment of @dell116 in the post.

Comment: I tried it as it is in `onCallStateChanged` method. I am getting newUri as `null`  why I don't no please help me..

Comment: soundFile= mCr.openAssetFileDescriptor(mUri, "r");

please tell me the meaning of this line...

Comment: mcr is a getContentResolver()

Answer (score 5):

Try this, it works for me:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, <<asbolutePathToYourAudioFileHere>>);
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "<<yourRingToneNameHere>>");
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, k);
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mpeg");    // assuming it's an mpeg, of course
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "<<yourArtistNameHere>>");
// values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION, duration);  // doesn't appear to be necessary if you don't know
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);

Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(outPath);  
Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);

RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                                <<MyActivity>>.this,
                                RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,
                                newUri);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully by now you have gotten your program working the way you wanted.  Just for the record though, you should look into saving the file to the sdcard under a ringtones folder. Make sure it is lower cased as that does matter in Android.

Answer (score -1):

I use "Rings Extended" http://www.androidapps.com/t/rings-extended

With that app installed when you go to change your ringtone you will have the option to select Rings Extended.  Also use "Ringdroid" to edit ringtones.

Comment: I want an example source code for incorporating this feature into my app.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/#svn/trunk/RingsExtended/src/com/example/android/rings_extended