# Can I play more than one file as a ringtone in android app?

Tags: android, ringtone

I want to play couple of files as one ringtone in android app, How can I do it?
edit: without merge

Comment: You mean doing an app that changes the ringtone of the device?

Comment: yes, but I want to play more than one audio file per persone
ringtone = more than one audio file

can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think is possible to use more than one ringtone without merging. I would do a merge and then setting it.

Check this threads:

- [setting-ringtone-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986756/setting-ringtone-in-android)
- [how-to-set-ringtone-in-android-from-my-activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271777/how-to-set-ringtone-in-android-from-my-activity)