# I am unable to set ringtone using activity in android studio?

Tags: android, ringtone, android-13, ringtonemanager, android-14

Sometimes it returns that unsupported **mimetype** and sometimes it returns **invalid token**

try to set ringtone in my app. But I am unable to do so by all mean I tried. I checked others code but I am not make it possible for me from others code. even all of these links provided below I didnt find my proper solution
[How to set Ringtone in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746746/how-to-set-ringtone-in-android)
[Setting Ringtone in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986756/setting-ringtone-in-android)
[How to set Android ringtone from audio file stored in external storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49676453/how-to-set-android-ringtone-from-audio-file-stored-in-external-storage)

Answer (score 0):

If you're facing issues setting a ringtone in your Android app and getting errors like "unsupported mimetype" or "invalid token," make sure to:

- Check your audio file format (e.g., MP3).
- Ensure you have the necessary permissions (WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and
  WRITE_SETTINGS).
- Verify the file path is correct and the file exists.
- Use the provided code to set the ringtone.
- Test your app on an Android device or emulator.

This should help you set a custom ringtone successfully.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to get the absolute path of ringtone that is going to be set ?