# Pick songs from SD card on Android and play it

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sdk-2.1, ringtone

I have songs in the Music folder on the SD card.

And in my app I want to **pick a song from SD card** from the list of music files, and when I choose any song, then using the Play button it should be played. How can I do that?

**I have already done it using content resolver and got a list of songs.** Is there a way to do this **using intents to pick from stored songs the SD card**?

I have done this by both the ways. Just check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check these to get an Idea,

http://androidgenuine.com/?tag=play-sound-android

[Setting Ringtone in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986756/setting-ringtone-in-android)

Comment: it is best not to post links but code snippets, since links may expire.

Answer (score 6):

Finally I got my answer.

**Code using intents is:**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    System.gc();
       Intent intent = new Intent();
       intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
       Uri data = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/Music");
       String type = "audio/mp3";
       intent.setDataAndType(data, type);
       startActivityForResult(intent, Pick_song);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch(requestCode)
    {
        case Pick_song : if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            muri = getIntent().getData();
            //String ringTonePath = muri.toString();

            if (muri != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    mMediaPlayer.start();
                    mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener()
                    {
                           @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
                           {
                               mp.release();
                            mp = null;
                        }
                    });
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: where should we pass music file Uri / path to MediaPlayer object?
Unluckily, I am unable to find that in the above code.

Answer (score 3):

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    System.gc();
    String[] listtype = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE };
    musiccursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,listtype, null, null, null);
    count = musiccursor.getCount();
    musiclist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneMusicList);
    musiclist.setAdapter(new MusicAdapter(this));
    musiclist.setOnItemClickListener(musicgridlistener);
    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    return true;
}
private OnItemClickListener musicgridlistener = new OnItemClickListener() 
{
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,long id)
    {
          System.gc();
          music_column_index = musiccursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
          musiccursor.moveToPosition(position);
          String filename = musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);
          try 
          {
                if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) 
                {
                      mMediaPlayer.reset();
                }
                mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(filename);
                mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                mMediaPlayer.start();
                mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) 
                    {
                        mp.release();
                        mp = null;                                   
                    }
                });     
          } 
          catch (Exception e) {}
    }
};

public class MusicAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
    private Context mContext;

    public MusicAdapter(Context c) 
    {
          mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() 
    {
          return count;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) 
    {
          return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
          return position;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
          System.gc();
          TextView tv = new TextView(mContext.getApplicationContext());
          String id = null;
          if (convertView == null) 
          {
                music_column_index = musiccursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
                musiccursor.moveToPosition(position);
                id = musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);
                music_column_index = musiccursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE);
                musiccursor.moveToPosition(position);
                id += " Size(KB):" + musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);
                tv.setText(id);
          } 
          else
          tv = (TextView) convertView;
          return tv;
    }       
}
}
```