# How can i know the url of sdcard for getting songs for ring tone?

Tags: android

I am new to android.
I am writing a small application that reads files from the SD card. It picks a song from the  SD card and then plays that song as a ring tone.

This is the code that plays the song:

```
MediaPlayer mp=MediaPlayer.create(Alarm.this, R.raw.airtel_new);
mp.start();
```

Instead of "`R.raw.airtel_new`" I would like to use the URI or the URL of a particular song that I have selected from the SD card.
Could any one help me?

Comment: Its easy, This link will be helpful to u.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035999/androidpick-songs-from-sd-card-and-play-it/7036162#7036162

Answer (score 1):

The root directory of your SDCard (where it is mounted) is known by `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()`.

So this allows you picking the file `/music/yourfile.ext` on the SD:

```
final String rootDir  = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
final String yourFile = rootDir + "/music/yourfile.ext";

final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(Alarm.this, "file://" + yourfile);
```

More details on this method are available [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create%28android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri%29).