# How to play song from list of songs based on this code

Tags: android

Here i am displaying all songs in on a listview ,i want to play that song based on onItemClick so suggest me how to do it based on my code
here is my code to display list of audio files from SDcard

```
public class ListFileActivity extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener {

private String path;
MediaPlayer mda;
int current_index2 = 0;
String filename;
Button backToRecord, allvoices;
ToggleButton activateDelete;
ListView myList;
List values;
ArrayAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.soundrecords);
     setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    backToRecord = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonrecord);
    activateDelete = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonedit);
    allvoices = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttoncontinuous);
    myList = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    backToRecord.setOnClickListener(this);
    activateDelete.setOnClickListener(this);
    allvoices.setOnClickListener(this);

    // Use the current directory as title
    path = "/sdcard/";
    if (getIntent().hasExtra("path")) {
        path = getIntent().getStringExtra("path");
    }
    setTitle(path);

    // Read all files sorted into the values-array
    values = new ArrayList();
    File dir = new File(path);
    if (!dir.canRead()) {
        setTitle(getTitle() + " (inaccessible)");
    }
    final String[] list = dir.list();
    if (list != null) {
        for (String file : list) {
            if (file.contains(".3gp")) {
                values.add(file);
            }
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(values);
    // Put the data into the list
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
            android.R.id.text1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    registerForContextMenu(myList);
}
```

Comment: Check it, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035999/androidpick-songs-from-sd-card-and-play-it

Answer (score 2):

Use onItemClick Listener and use a `MediaPlayer` object the play the audio from the file from the clicked item's uri

```
mylist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setDataSource(path+mylist.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
mp.prepare();
mp.play();

    }
});
```

}

Comment: i Know this ,http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/ this explains my solutions,but could you check my code and update your ans

Comment: Yeah wait till i type this

Comment: What is the Path? try to System.out.println(path+mylist.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()) and comment it

Comment: Here whay is mylist? ,if i changed to myList then it is showing create a methos with name setDataResource.

Comment: myList is the name of your listView and i forgot to add mp.setDataSource();

Comment: When i changed mylist to myList then it is showing above error

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43654/discussion-between-insomniac-and-prabha)