# setting raw resource as a ringtone

Tags: android, ringtone

I have read these 2 posts [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986756/setting-ringtone-in-android) and this one [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271777/how-to-set-ringtone-in-android-from-my-activity) but code does not seem to work for me.

Here is my code:

```
File newSoundFile = new File("/sdcard/media/ringtone", "myringtone.oog");
            Uri mUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.pack.android.myapp/R.raw.song1");
            ContentResolver mCr = Main.this.getContentResolver();
            AssetFileDescriptor soundFile;
            try {
                   soundFile= mCr.openAssetFileDescriptor(mUri, "r");
               } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                   soundFile=null;   
               }

               try {
                  byte[] readData = new byte[1024];
                  FileInputStream fis = soundFile.createInputStream();
                  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newSoundFile);
                  int i = fis.read(readData);

                  while (i != -1) {
                    fos.write(readData, 0, i);
                    i = fis.read(readData);
                  }

                  fos.close();
               } catch (IOException io) {
               }
               ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
               values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, newSoundFile.getAbsolutePath());
               values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "my ringtone");
               values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/oog");
               values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, newSoundFile.length());
               values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, R.string.app_name);
               values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
               values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
               values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
               values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

               Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(newSoundFile.getAbsolutePath());
               Uri newUri = mCr.insert(uri, values);


               try {
                   RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(Main.this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);
               } catch (Throwable t) {
                  // Log.d(TAG, "catch exception");
               }
```

and I am getting a force close. Logcat is here:

```
06-30 03:13:03.731: E/AndroidRuntime(4187): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-30 03:13:03.731: E/AndroidRuntime(4187): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-30 03:13:03.731: E/AndroidRuntime(4187):     at com.pack.android.myapp.Main.Music(Main.java:83)
06-30 03:13:03.731: E/AndroidRuntime(4187):     at com.pack.android.myapp.Main$2.onClick(Main.java:46)
06-30 03:13:03.731: E/AndroidRuntime(4187):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
06-30 03:13:03.731: E/AndroidRuntime(4187):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
06-30 03:13:03.731: E/AndroidRuntime(4187):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-30 03:13:03.731: E/AndroidRuntime(4187):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-30 03:13:03.731: E/AndroidRuntime(4187):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-30 03:13:03.731: E/AndroidRuntime(4187):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
06-30 03:13:03.731: E/AndroidRuntime(4187):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-30 03:13:03.731: E/AndroidRuntime(4187):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-30 03:13:03.731: E/AndroidRuntime(4187):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
06-30 03:13:03.731: E/AndroidRuntime(4187):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
06-30 03:13:03.731: E/AndroidRuntime(4187):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

soundFile seems to be null. Why is that? My song is song1.mpe and is in the raw folder under the res.

Permission added in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: the given answer works for u ???@ghostrider

Answer (score 3):

Put your ringtone sound in assets folder and use this code

```
Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://yourpackagename/raw/yoursoundfile")
RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                    getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,
                    path);
            Log .i("TESTT", "Ringtone Set to Resource: "+ path.toString());
            RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), path)
                    .play();
```

Add this permission to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me either. Its set as a ringtone the default sound of my mobile, and the I also get a force close with a null pointer exception.

Comment: The uri string is wrong for placing the ringtone in the assets folder. As written above, the ringtone would need to be in the the res/**raw** folder.

If you place the ringtone in the assets folder, the uri string should be:
"android.resource://yourpackagename/**assets**/yoursoundfile")

Comment: @Baron Do I need to save the ringtone into the storage before can actually plays it?

Comment: This needs system app permission which you cannot use in a normal app..

Answer (score 0):

This is the code i used! very helpfull to me especially this [tutorial](http://programondaspot.blogspot.com/2015/09/set-raw-resource-file-as-ringtone-in.html) !

```
 String exStoragePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
 String path=(exStoragePath +"/media/alarms/"); 

saveas(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);

sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+path+filename+".mp3"
      + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()))); 


File k = new File(path, filename);

ContentValues values = new ContentValues(4);
long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, path + filename  );
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE,  filename );
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED, (int) (current / 1000));
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/3gpp");

 //new
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "cssounds ");
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);  

// Insert it into the database
 this.getContentResolver()
.insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k
 .getAbsolutePath()), values);
```

HAPPY CODING!