# Alter Ringtone Settings in Android using Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I am considering PhoneGap for my first android project because I have had plenty of experience with HTML5 before. But before I start going deeper into phonegap, i want to make sure if phonegap provides all the features that I need for the project..

My app should be able to change the ringtone settings (volume and vibration settings) of the device. So, I wanted to know if this is possible using PhoneGap.

I looked into PhoneGap's documentation and couldnt find anything. I even tried asking this question in their google group but i thought asking the question here in stack overflow would be much faster.

And if it is not possible using PhoneGap... are there any workarounds??

Sincerely,
Aayush Shrestha

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write your own plugin for this - Cordova does not do this out the box, because it's quite platform specific.

Take a look at the following link to find out how to natively alter the ringtone: [Setting Ringtone in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986756/setting-ringtone-in-android).

You will then need to convert that to a plugin (which should not be too difficult - there are plenty of examples at: http://plugins.cordova.io/ which you can download and inspect).

Hope that helps!