# Uri MediaPlayer Android Internal Storage

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, internal-storage

I want to integrate my app with a MediaPlayer, but I can't play music that are in the internal storage.
Actually I have only 1 song in the "Music" folder. I can't play it.
This is my code:

```
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC;
try {
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, uri);
    mediaPlayer.prepare();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: Please check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986756/setting-ringtone-in-android

Answer (score 0):

This techniques is ok if and only if you want to play one sound depending on your condition. Set URI as follow:

```
Uri soundUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName()
                + "/" + R.raw.sound);
```

other way would be:

```
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(pathToFolderSDCard);
```