# How to access all ringtones list in Android phone?

Tags: android, ringtone, ringtonemanager

I want to access the ringtones list. How can I do that?

At later I want to add/ remove ring tones to library? Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`RingtoneManager`](http://d.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html) to access all the existing ringtones.

[Have a look at this question for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271777/how-to-set-ringtone-in-android-from-my-activity) of how to add ringtones.

Comment: That's great.RingtoneManager allows access to each ringtone files. 
There is no API avaiable to add/remove ringtones.

is it possible to add/remove ringtones?

Comment: @Jim - just edited the question to link to a question which shows you how to add ringtones.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to access the ringtone file

```
File racine = getDatabasePath("/system/media/audio/ringtones");

   final File[] liste = racine.listFiles();
    if (liste == null) return;
   final  int lng = liste.length;
    if (lng == 0) return;
```