# How can I get my ringtone to play in android?

Tags: android, ringtone

I'm making a soundboard application and am trying to have a sound play as a ringtone or notification depending on which menu item is clicked. The ringtone currently shows up as the default ringtone in the ringtone menu, but does not play when a phone call comes in. What am I doing wrong? My code is listed below.

```
public boolean saveas(int ressound,String file,String typesound){
    byte[] buffer=null;  
    InputStream fIn = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(ressound);  
    int size=0;  

    try {  
        size = fIn.available();  
        buffer = new byte[size];  
        fIn.read(buffer);  
        fIn.close();  
    } catch (IOException e) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
        return false;  
    }  

    String path="/sdcard/media/audio/ringtones/";  
    String filename=file+".ogg";  

    boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();  
    if (!exists){new File(path).mkdirs();}  

    FileOutputStream save;  
    try {  
        save = new FileOutputStream(path+filename);  
        save.write(buffer);  
        save.flush();  
        save.close();  
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
        return false;  
    } catch (IOException e) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
        return false;  
    }      

    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://"+path+filename)));  

    File k = new File(path, filename);  

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();  
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());  
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, file);  
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/ogg");  
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "douchebag");  
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);  
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);  
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);  
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);  

    //Insert it into the database  
    this.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath()), values);  

    //set ringtone
    Uri ringtoneUri = Uri.parse(path+filename);
    if(typesound=="ringtone")
        RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, ringtoneUri);

    return true;  
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error? What is the behaviour you are seeing? Also, try logging when you catch an exception if it cause your app to not function as expected.

Answer (score 1):

According to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271777/how-to-set-ringtone-in-android-from-my-activity), you need to set the ringtone with the "external" URI. As far as I can tell, you basically have all the pieces and just need to make a tiny adjustment.

Try if this snippet works for you:

```
//Insert it into the database
Uri ringtoneUri = this.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath()), values); 
//set ringtone    
if(typesound=="ringtone")
    RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, ringtoneUri);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FullBatteryAlarm.prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String strRingtonePrefs = FullBatteryAlarm.prefs.getString(
            FullBatteryAlarm.res.getString(R.string.ringtone), "content://settings/system/alarm_alert");
    //Log.i("strringtone", strRingtonePrefs);
    Uri notification = Uri.parse(strRingtonePrefs);

    AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    //mgr.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
    mgr.setStreamVolume(
            AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 
            mgr.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING),
            AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
    //Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onStart()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

OR you can get your default notification sound.

```
Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
    r.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hey,  I think you need to set the permission in the android manifest.
Below is the permission I used.**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" ></uses-permission>
```

**Also I'm not sure about ogg files.  I used mp3 files and it worked for me.**