# I want to change the ringtone permanently as per my given media

Tags: android

Here is the code

```
        File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/Audio/MI2.MID");
        Uri Note=Uri.fromFile(dir);

        RingtoneManager.getDefaultType(Note);
        RingtoneManager.isDefault(Note);
        RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, Note);
```

But It is setting my phone's default ringtone..

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked through other posts? There are a few on this topic. On a quick search this one came up with some code and a quick tip on permissions too! [How can I change the ringtone in android programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182891/how-can-i-change-the-ringtone-in-android-programmatically) :)