# Set a selected audio mp3 file as ringtone

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to set an audio file as a ringtone, I have in the Raw file several mp3 and a listView contains the name of mp3, I would like when I click on the listview changes the phone ringtone

Comment: I suggest you search stack next time as this already has an answer.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182891/how-can-i-change-the-ringtone-in-android-programmatically

Be aware though that a custom dialer program has no requirement to respect those settings at all.  As a side note, it really annoys me how people drive-by downvote questions without explaining why, and especially when similar questions have dozens of upvotes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the ringtone in android programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182891/how-can-i-change-the-ringtone-in-android-programmatically)