# How to set ringtone in Android to downloaded audio?

Tags: android, ringtone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set ringtone in Android from my activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271777/how-to-set-ringtone-in-android-from-my-activity)

What I want to do in my app is to create a single button, and whenever that button is pressed, I want the audio to be downloaded and set it as a ringtone when the download is finished. But the problem is, I really don't know how to set the download object as a ringtone. I know how to download audio.

Comment: Take a look at the answer @PHP_Jedi wrote in [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271777/how-to-set-ringtone-in-android-from-my-activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully not possible, as that would be quite disturbing if an app could just change your ringtone. But then again, I haven't intensively studied the subject so I can't tell for sure.