# How to override SMS ringtone

Tags: android, notifications, sms, ringtone

What I want to do:
To set my ringtone to incoming `SMS` even though there is another one in the `SMS app`.

What I tried:
In `SMS reciever`, I set volume of `STREAM_NOTIFICATION to 0` and than tried to play my ringtone as media via `MediaPlayer`.

So basically something like this:

```
am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, 0, 0);
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, notifUri);
mp.start();
int duration = mp.getDuration() + 3000;  //Margin
try {
   Thread.sleep(duration);
 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
 }
am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, beforOverrideNotifVol, 0);
```

What happened:
My custom ringtone played but immediately after this, the `sms-app` sound rang too.
I tried to add some more sleep to the thread (to let the sms-app play on background) but it just waits for the volume to restore and then plays its ringtone.

At first I tried this:

```
 RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(...)
```

But it doesn't override the app-setting, it only overrides notification sounds when the ringtone is chosen in the sms-app.

Comment: Hope this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271777/how-to-set-ringtone-in-android-from-my-activity) will help you:)

Answer (score 0):

For me Ringtonemanger.setDefaultRingtoneUri worked

Try using this to choose ringtone and then set it

```
 private void chooseTone(int Id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE,
            RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "Select Tone");
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, (Uri) null);
    MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(intent, NotificationId);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent intent) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri uri = intent
                .getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Tone: " + uri);

            if (uri != null)
                this.chosenRingtone = uri;
    }}
```

And then finally to set the ringtone
    RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(MainActivity.this,
                RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, chosenRingtone);

Comment: I've already tried that. The problem is that this doesnt work when you have the ringtone chosen in the sms-app. It overrides only the default setting for notifications (and sms if its not chosen in the sms-app)