# How to set MP3 as Ringtone

Tags: android, media-player

I am writing an app in which i am showing list of MP3 Songs from Raw folder, and allowing user to Play song by using click on button, in a same way i want to allow user to set song as Ringtone, which one user has clicked in a List Button, please see below screen shot:

**List of MP3 Songs:**

[image]

**Showing selected song in PlayActivity.java:**

[image]

**PlayActivity:**

```
                // Set as Ringtone
        btn5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {                               
         Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.applenty/raw/");
         RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
         getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, path);
         Log .i("Ringtone", "Ringtone Set to Resource:: "+ path.toString());
         RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), path).play();

            }
        });
```

**Logcat:**

```
07-10 12:06:05.569: D/dalvikvm(958): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 37K, 7% free 2486K/2648K, paused 130ms, total 147ms
07-10 12:06:05.630: I/dalvikvm-heap(958): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.153MB for 635812-byte allocation
07-10 12:06:05.719: D/dalvikvm(958): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 6% free 3105K/3272K, paused 90ms, total 90ms
07-10 12:06:05.869: D/dalvikvm(958): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 5% free 3121K/3272K, paused 4ms+23ms, total 137ms
07-10 12:06:05.939: D/data count(958): 5//
07-10 12:06:05.979: D/data count(958): 5//
07-10 12:06:05.979: D/data count(958): 5//
07-10 12:06:06.189: D/data count(958): 5//
07-10 12:06:06.210: D/data count(958): 5//
07-10 12:06:06.319: D/data count(958): 5//
07-10 12:06:06.350: D/data count(958): 5//
07-10 12:06:06.519: D/data count(958): 5//
07-10 12:06:06.779: I/Choreographer(958): Skipped 163 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-10 12:06:06.800: D/data count(958): 5//
07-10 12:06:06.800: D/data count(958): 5//
07-10 12:06:06.889: D/data count(958): 5//
07-10 12:06:06.909: D/data count(958): 5//
07-10 12:06:06.929: D/data count(958): 5//
07-10 12:06:06.979: D/gralloc_goldfish(958): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
07-10 12:06:07.439: D/data count(958): 5//
07-10 12:06:07.449: D/data count(958): 5//
07-10 12:06:07.579: D/data count(958): 5//
07-10 12:06:07.579: D/data count(958): 5//
07-10 12:06:07.689: D/data count(958): 5//
07-10 12:07:59.060: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(958): KeyEvent: ACTION_UP but key was not down.
07-10 12:07:59.060: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(958):   in android.view.ViewRootImpl@40ce0838
07-10 12:07:59.060: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(958):   0: sent at 214631000000, KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_MENU, scanCode=229, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=214631, downTime=214548, deviceId=0, source=0x101 }
07-10 12:07:59.939: D/data count(958): 5//
07-10 12:07:59.939: D/data count(958): 5//
07-10 12:08:00.050: D/data count(958): 5//
07-10 12:08:00.060: D/data count(958): 5//
07-10 12:08:00.119: D/data count(958): 5//
07-10 12:08:08.449: D/dalvikvm(958): GC_CONCURRENT freed 36K, 5% free 3573K/3736K, paused 15ms+58ms, total 346ms
07-10 12:08:13.849: I/Choreographer(958): Skipped 120 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-10 12:08:22.159: I/Ringtone(958): Ringtone Set to Resource:: android.resource://com.applenty/raw/
07-10 12:08:22.190: D/MediaPlayer(958): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
07-10 12:08:22.210: E/MediaPlayer(958): error (1, -2147483648)
07-10 12:08:22.219: D/Ringtone(958): Problem opening; delegating to remote player
07-10 12:08:55.779: I/Ringtone(958): Ringtone Set to Resource:: android.resource://com.applenty/raw/
07-10 12:08:55.779: D/MediaPlayer(958): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
07-10 12:08:55.799: E/MediaPlayer(958): error (1, -2147483648)
07-10 12:08:55.799: D/Ringtone(958): Problem opening; delegating to remote player
07-10 12:08:57.089: I/Ringtone(958): Ringtone Set to Resource:: android.resource://com.applenty/raw/
07-10 12:08:57.100: D/MediaPlayer(958): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
07-10 12:08:57.109: E/MediaPlayer(958): error (1, -2147483648)
07-10 12:08:57.119: D/Ringtone(958): Problem opening; delegating to remote player
07-10 12:09:02.779: I/Ringtone(958): Ringtone Set to Resource:: android.resource://com.applenty/raw/
07-10 12:09:02.789: D/MediaPlayer(958): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
07-10 12:09:02.799: E/MediaPlayer(958): error (1, -2147483648)
07-10 12:09:02.809: D/Ringtone(958): Problem opening; delegating to remote player
07-10 12:09:07.239: I/Ringtone(958): Ringtone Set to Resource:: android.resource://com.applenty/raw/
07-10 12:09:07.249: D/MediaPlayer(958): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
07-10 12:09:07.269: E/MediaPlayer(958): error (1, -2147483648)
07-10 12:09:07.269: D/Ringtone(958): Problem opening; delegating to remote player
07-10 12:09:08.589: I/Ringtone(958): Ringtone Set to Resource:: android.resource://com.applenty/raw/
07-10 12:09:08.589: D/MediaPlayer(958): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that the path is correct this is one way you can set the song to a ringtone taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271777/how-to-set-ringtone-in-android-from-my-activity):

```
File k = new File(path, "mysong.mp3"); // path is a file playing

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "My Song title"); //You will have to populate 
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, 215454);
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "Band Name"); //You will have to populate this
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION, 230);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

//Insert it into the database
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath());
Uri newUri = main.getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);

RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
  myActivity,
  RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,
  newUri
);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this one, it's good for you

```
File newSoundFile = new File("pathFile");
        if (DebugUtil.DEBUG) {
            DebugUtil.logError(new Exception(), newSoundFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, newSoundFile.getAbsolutePath());
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, songVO.getTitle());
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/*");
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, newSoundFile.length());
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, R.string.app_name);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION, 230);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(newSoundFile.getAbsolutePath());
        context.getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + newSoundFile.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);
        Uri newUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);

        try {
            RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);
            KitKatToast.makeText(context, R.string.msg_setAsRingTuneSuccess, KitKatToast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            if (DebugUtil.DEBUG) {
                DebugUtil.logError(new Exception(), e.toString());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this one:

this is on click mec

```
btn5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {                               
            MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(FakeCallScreen.this, R.raw.mysoundfile);
            mPlayer.start();
        }
});

public void onDestroy() {
    mPlayer.stop();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Add permission in Manifest File:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: How to set MP3 as Ringtone using raw Folder?

Comment: you have mp3 file then copy and paste into raw folder.then postion of the list set ring tome of mp3.to play this code.

Comment: i have 5 ringtones in raw folder

Comment: you are using listview and get the position of each view.you will be use the view.set on click and get the position of each view you can check each position of the view like that if(position==1){ btn5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { public void onClick(View v) {

MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(FakeCallScreen.this, R.raw.mysoundfile); mPlayer.start(); } });}

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33265/discussion-between-nitesh-khosla-and-chulbul-pandey)