# Change ringtone from code

Tags: java, android

guys. I'm going to write one application and have one question.

How can I change ringtone from my code and how can I catch call event.

Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set ringtone in Android from my activity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271777/how-to-set-ringtone-in-android-from-my-activity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the ringtone from code as follows:

```
File k = new File(path, "mysong.mp3"); // path is a file to /sdcard/media/ringtone

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "My Song title");
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, 215454);
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "Madonna");
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION, 230);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

//Insert it into the database
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath());
Uri newUri = main.getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);

RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
  myActivity,
  RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,
  newUri
);
```