# Use a mp3 raw as ringtone

Tags: android

How I use and save a mp3 file in raw as ringtone?

I already put this code but doesnt work:

```html
Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://mypack/raw/soundmp3");
RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getApplicationContext(),RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,path);
Log.i("TESTT", "Ringtone Set to Resource: " + path.toString());
RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), path).play();
```

I already using the permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set ringtone in Android from my activity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271777/how-to-set-ringtone-in-android-from-my-activity)

Answer (score -1):

```
int resID=getResources().getIdentifier(fname, "raw", getPackageName());

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this,resID);
mediaPlayer.start();


 You can not save anything on runtime in raw folder coz it is read-only.
 You have to put your file in raw folder before making a build.
```

Comment: I think the OP means to save that ringtone as a default setting for his phone.

Comment: What must I put in fname?