# Set .mp3 file as ringtone from assets

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to set a .mp3 file sited into /assets folder as ringtone. This is my code

```
File file = new File("file:///android_asset/my_sounds/", name);

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, file.getAbsolutePath());
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, name.replace(".mp3", ""));
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, file.length());
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, 
        media.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST));
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION, 
        media.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION));

uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(file.getAbsolutePath());
mUri = getContext().getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);       

RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getContext(), 
        RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, mUri);
```

When I go to settings (settings of the phone) I see the name of the song that I set as ringtone but when someone calls me, it plays the old ringtone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set ringtone in Android from my activity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271777/how-to-set-ringtone-in-android-from-my-activity)

Answer (score 1):

```
File file = new File("file:///android_asset/my_sounds/", name);

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, file.getAbsolutePath());
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, name.replace(".mp3", ""));
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, file.length());
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, 
        media.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST));
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION, 
        media.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION));
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);       

uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(file.getAbsolutePath());
mUri = getContext().getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);


RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getContext(), 
        RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, mUri);
```

You have placed ringtone after setting it to mUri.