# How to set ringtone in Android, using ringtone manager?

Tags: android, android-audiomanager, ringtonemanager

I am using the following code, but it doesn't seem to change the ringtone. What am I doing wrong, or is there an easier way to set an mp3 to ringtone? I have a uri that parses the location, and I call the following function. I know the uri is correct because it functions correctly with a file share method I have.

```
private void setRingtone(Uri uri) {
        AssetFileDescriptor openAssetFileDescriptor;
        ((AudioManager) getActivity().getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE)).setRingerMode(2);
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/appkeeda", mp3s[position]);
        if (!file.getParentFile().exists()) {
            file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        }
        if (!file.exists()) {
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
        try {
            openAssetFileDescriptor = contentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
            openAssetFileDescriptor = null;
        }
        try {
            byte[] bArr = new byte[1024];
            FileInputStream createInputStream = openAssetFileDescriptor.createInputStream();
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            for (int read = createInputStream.read(bArr); read != -1; read = createInputStream.read(bArr)) {
                fileOutputStream.write(bArr, 0, read);
            }
            fileOutputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e3) {
            e3.printStackTrace();
        }
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("_data", file.getAbsolutePath());
        contentValues.put("title", "nkDroid ringtone");
        contentValues.put("mime_type", "audio/mp3");
        contentValues.put("_size", Long.valueOf(file.length()));
        contentValues.put("artist", Integer.valueOf(R.string.app_name));
        contentValues.put("is_ringtone", Boolean.valueOf(true));
        contentValues.put("is_notification", Boolean.valueOf(false));
        contentValues.put("is_alarm", Boolean.valueOf(false));
        contentValues.put("is_music", Boolean.valueOf(false));
        try {
            //Toast.makeText(this, new StringBuilder().append("Ringtone set successfully"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getActivity().getBaseContext(), 1, contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(file.getAbsolutePath()), contentValues));
        } catch (Throwable th) {
            //Toast.makeText(this, new StringBuilder().append("Ringtone feature is not working"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271777/how-to-set-ringtone-in-android-from-my-activity

Comment: doesn't work but thank you, I think the code might be outdated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: This tutorial worked for me: http://blog.nkdroidsolutions.com/set-default-ringtone-raw-folder-programmatically-android/